# Error when running envdte project from console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application, envdte, extensibility

I am trying to make work some code I created in an add-in, from console.

I am getting errors:

```
Error in solution file: C:\x\x.sln
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010001): Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))
   at EnvDTE.Project.get_Kind()
   at p.Program.Projects(DTE2 dte) in C:\z\p\Program.cs:line 764
   at ..
   at p.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\z\p\Program.cs:line 60
```

The code:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
...
class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {  
    EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte;
    object obj = null;
    System.Type t = null;
    t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0", true);
    obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);
    dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)obj;
    string[] solutionFile = ...
    dte.Solution.Open(solutionFile);
    EnvDTE.Solution solution = (EnvDTE.Solution)dte.Solution;
    IList<Project> projects = Projects((DTE2)dte);
          ...    
  }
private static IList<Project> Projects(DTE2 dte)
    {
      Projects projects = dte.Solution.Projects;
      List<Project> list = new List<Project>();
      var item = projects.GetEnumerator();
      while (item.MoveNext())
      {
         var project = item.Current as Project;
         if (project == null)
         {
            continue;
         }
         if (string.Compare(EnvDTE.Constants.vsProjectKindUnmodeled, project.Kind, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)  // this is line 764
         {
             throw some_exception;
         }
         if (project.Kind == ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder)
         {
             ...
         }
      }
    }
  }
```

Initially, Intellisense was telling me

```
Interop type 'DTE2.ProjectKinds' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.
```

I found a reference telling me that I can go to my Reference Properties, and set the `Embed Interop Assembly` to `False`

That allowed me to build without error.... but the execution gives me the error above.

Please help - how can I fix this ?

VS2010... It works in an add-in...

Comment: This is not an add-in scenario by any stretch of the imagination.  You are running a console mode program and you are starting Visual Studio as an out-of-process COM server.  You'll see devenv.exe in Taskmgr.exe's Process tab.  To what degree it gets cranky about being commandeered by another process is fairly unguessable.  Get ahead by actually creating an add-in, there's a project template for it.

Comment: I betcha your DTE instance just hasn't gotten to the point where it can handle calls when you try to access its properties.  Try putting a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` call in there before your exception point.  Increase the sleep time if one second doesn't work.

Comment: @Hans: I already created an add-in, that modifies solutions - I wanted to make it easier to modify them when changes are required in over 100 solutions. That is why I am trying to adapt the add-in code to work from a command line, and iterate through all solutions.

Comment: Avoid thinking "add-in", you are automating VS.  I like Will's comment, having such synchronization problems are certainly conceivable when your code doesn't run inside of VS. This doesn't get put to the test very often.  Console programs are also notorious for causing automation problems, you could randomly try putting the [STAThread] attribute on the Main() method.

Comment: Ah, you already did, never mind.  Having to pump a message loop is an STA thread requirement, Application.Run().

Comment: @Will thank you, you were correct. I actually have found a reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.100).aspx but I didn't understand it, until now.

Comment: Thank you Hans, I actually had [STAThread] before Main. What does it mean, pumping a message loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will's comment above was the answer to my question -

I ended up using the following reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.100).aspx